# Breaking Up Rows With Intervals Spanning over an hour / Issues with Time Conversion in R

Tags: r

I have data with IDs, close times, and open times. I need to break out up each line that spans over an hour into multiple rows with for each ID, such that each row has an open and close time not spanning over the top of the hour. Ideally, this would leave rows that have open and close times within the same hour alone. It would also retain the ID throughout each row.

For example, if I have an open time from 11:55am to 1:10pm - I would want three rows to result from this respective column. One from 11:55 - 12, 12 - 1, and 1 - 1:10.

I believe I have come up with a solution, but it is convoluted:

```
dat <- tibble(ID = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L),
                  open_time = structure(c( 1509378717, 1509475803, 1509460317, 1509372561, 1508445791, 1508962523, 1509483224, 1509483978, 1509483727),
                                        tzone = "America/New_York",
                                        class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")),
                  close_time = structure(c( 1509383226, 1509476435, 1509462052, 1509376589, 1508445791, 1508962523, 1509483543, 1509483983, 1509483727),
                                         tzone = "America/New_York",
                                         class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")))

split_by_hour <- function(open_time, close_time){

  # get hours to span
  hour_start <- lubridate::ceiling_date(open_time, 'hour')
  hour_end <- lubridate::floor_date(close_time, 'hour')

  # hour sequence to create rows
  hour_seq <- seq(hour_start, hour_end, by = 'hour')

  # create tibble
  time_tbl <- tibble(
    open_time = lubridate::ymd_hms(c(open_time, hour_seq), tz = "America/New_York"),
    close_time = lubridate::ymd_hms(c(hour_seq, close_time), tz = "America/New_York")
  )

  time_tbl
}

row_hour_breakout <- function(rw){

  if(lubridate::floor_date(rw$open_time, 'hour') != lubridate::floor_date(rw$close_time, 'hour')){
    # if hours are different, use helper function and bind columns
    time_splits <- split_by_hour(rw$open_time, rw$close_time)
    dplyr::bind_cols(ID = rep(rw$ID, nrow(time_splits)),
                     time_splits)
  } else{
    # else return normal row
    rw[, c("ID", "open_time", "close_time")] 
  }
}

break_tbl_hourly <- function(hour_dat){
  purrr::by_row(hour_dat, row_hour_breakout, .labels = FALSE)[[1]] %>%
    dplyr::bind_rows()
}

>dat
# A tibble: 9 x 3
     ID           open_time          close_time
  <int>              <dttm>              <dttm>
1     2 2017-10-30 11:51:57 2017-10-30 13:07:06
2     1 2017-10-31 14:50:03 2017-10-31 15:00:35
3     2 2017-10-31 10:31:57 2017-10-31 11:00:52
4     1 2017-10-30 10:09:21 2017-10-30 11:16:29
5     2 2017-10-19 16:43:11 2017-10-19 16:43:11
6     1 2017-10-25 16:15:23 2017-10-25 16:15:23
7     2 2017-10-31 16:53:44 2017-10-31 16:59:03
8     1 2017-10-31 17:06:18 2017-10-31 17:06:23
9     2 2017-10-31 17:02:07 2017-10-31 17:02:07

> break_tbl_hourly(dat)
# A tibble: 14 x 3
      ID           open_time          close_time
   <int>              <dttm>              <dttm>
 1     2 2017-10-30 11:51:57 2017-10-30 12:00:00
 2     2 2017-10-30 12:00:00 2017-10-30 13:00:00
 3     2 2017-10-30 13:00:00 2017-10-30 13:07:06
 4     1 2017-10-31 14:50:03 2017-10-31 15:00:00
 5     1 2017-10-31 15:00:00 2017-10-31 15:00:35
 6     2 2017-10-31 10:31:57 2017-10-31 11:00:00
 7     2 2017-10-31 11:00:00 2017-10-31 11:00:52
 8     1 2017-10-30 10:09:21 2017-10-30 11:00:00
 9     1 2017-10-30 11:00:00 2017-10-30 11:16:29
10     2 2017-10-19 20:43:11 2017-10-19 20:43:11
11     1 2017-10-25 20:15:23 2017-10-25 20:15:23
12     2 2017-10-31 20:53:44 2017-10-31 20:59:03
13     1 2017-10-31 21:06:18 2017-10-31 21:06:23
14     2 2017-10-31 21:02:07 2017-10-31 21:02:07
```

Ultimately, I would like to know:

1. Where this code can be improved. It does not feel like good code, but it took me some time to get here, so I'm turning to StackOverflow for help
2. <del>Why it is converting the rows that are not changed to UTC (+4 hours) time?</del> Edit: time zone issue in split_by_hour function was culprit.

Thank you!

=====================================

follow up, i've written a function to do this, based on the solution above:

```
# break rows function

# df: data frame of interest
# begin_time_var: variable of beginning times
# end_time_var: variable of ending times

break_rows_hourly <- function(df, begin_time_var, end_time_var){

  begin <- enquo(begin_time_var)
  end <- enquo(end_time_var)

  #######################################
  #
  # to be applied to each open/close time
  #
  #######################################

  split_by_hour <- function(open_time, close_time){

    # ensure open time is at least before close time
    if(open_time <= close_time){

      # get hours to span
      hour_start <- lubridate::ceiling_date(open_time, 'hour')
      hour_end <- lubridate::floor_date(close_time, 'hour')

      # check if hourly difference
      if(hour_start <= hour_end){
        #
        # if it is, then go on to create multiple rows
        #

        # hour sequence to create rows
        hour_seq <- seq(hour_start, hour_end, by = 'hour')

        # create tibble
        time_tbl <- tibble(
          open_time = lubridate::ymd_hms(c(open_time, hour_seq)),
          close_time = lubridate::ymd_hms(c(hour_seq, close_time))
        )
        return(time_tbl)
      } else {
        #
        # hour start > hour end, return 1 row
        #

        # create tibble
        time_tbl <- tibble(
          open_time = open_time,
          close_time = close_time
        )
        return(time_tbl)
      }
    } else {
      #
      # open time greater than close time, error printed statement
      #
      print("Close Time Before Open Time")
    }
  }

  #######################################
  #
  # applies split by row and creates a df
  #
  #######################################
  row_hour_breakout <- function(rw){

    # split row
    time_splits <- split_by_hour(rw %>% select(!!begin) %>% pull(), rw %>% select(!!end) %>% pull())

    # get orther columns
    other_cols <- rw %>% 
      select(-!!begin, - !!end) %>%
      map(function(x) rep(x, nrow(time_splits))) %>%
      as.tibble()

    dplyr::bind_cols(other_cols,
                     time_splits)
  }

  #######################################
  #
  # map to each row, rbind to return
  #
  #######################################
  return_df <- purrr::by_row(df, row_hour_breakout, .labels = FALSE)[[1]] %>%
    dplyr::bind_rows()

  return(return_df)
}

> break_rows_hourly(dat, open_time, close_time)
# A tibble: 14 x 3
      ID           open_time          close_time
   <int>              <dttm>              <dttm>
 1     2 2017-10-30 11:51:57 2017-10-30 12:00:00
 2     2 2017-10-30 12:00:00 2017-10-30 13:00:00
 3     2 2017-10-30 13:00:00 2017-10-30 13:07:06
 4     1 2017-10-31 14:50:03 2017-10-31 15:00:00
 5     1 2017-10-31 15:00:00 2017-10-31 15:00:35
 6     2 2017-10-31 10:31:57 2017-10-31 11:00:00
 7     2 2017-10-31 11:00:00 2017-10-31 11:00:52
 8     1 2017-10-30 10:09:21 2017-10-30 11:00:00
 9     1 2017-10-30 11:00:00 2017-10-30 11:16:29
10     2 2017-10-19 20:43:11 2017-10-19 20:43:11
11     1 2017-10-25 20:15:23 2017-10-25 20:15:23
12     2 2017-10-31 20:53:44 2017-10-31 20:59:03
13     1 2017-10-31 21:06:18 2017-10-31 21:06:23
14     2 2017-10-31 21:02:07 2017-10-31 21:02:07
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the split-apply-combine strategy.  In this case, we have to process one by one each row in `dat`.  So the whole thing would look like

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(dat, seq(nrow(dat))), expand.row))
```

where `expand.row` is a function that takes a data-frame containing
exactly one row and outputs a data frame containing one or more rows.

The `split(...)` part creates a list of 1-row data-frames. `lapply(..., expand.row)` applies `expand.row` to each element in the list and collects the results in a different list. `do.call(rbind, ...)` stacks the elements in the second list on top of one another in order to get the resulting data frame.

All we have to do now is write `expand.row`.

```
expand.row <- function(x) {
    with(x, {
        h <- trunc(open_time, 'hour') + 3600 # nearest full hour > open_time
        if (h > close_time)
            p <- c(open_time, close_time)
        else
            p <- unique(c(open_time, seq(h, close_time, 3600), close_time))
        n <- length(p)
        data.frame(ID = ID, open_time = p[seq(1, n - 1)],
                   close_time = p[seq(2, n)])
    })
}
```

Result:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(dat, seq(nrow(dat))), expand.row))
#    ID           open_time          close_time
#1.1  2 2017-10-30 16:51:57 2017-10-30 17:00:00
#1.2  2 2017-10-30 17:00:00 2017-10-30 18:00:00
#1.3  2 2017-10-30 18:00:00 2017-10-30 18:07:06
#2.1  1 2017-10-31 19:50:03 2017-10-31 20:00:00
#2.2  1 2017-10-31 20:00:00 2017-10-31 20:00:35
#3.1  2 2017-10-31 15:31:57 2017-10-31 16:00:00
#3.2  2 2017-10-31 16:00:00 2017-10-31 16:00:52
#4.1  1 2017-10-30 15:09:21 2017-10-30 16:00:00
#4.2  1 2017-10-30 16:00:00 2017-10-30 16:16:29
#5    2 2017-10-19 22:43:11 2017-10-19 22:43:11
#6    1 2017-10-25 22:15:23 2017-10-25 22:15:23
#7    2 2017-10-31 21:53:44 2017-10-31 21:59:03
#8    1 2017-10-31 22:06:18 2017-10-31 22:06:23
#9    2 2017-10-31 22:02:07 2017-10-31 22:02:07
```